# Why are the "edit" and "retag" links missing from this post?

Tags: support, editing

I saw this question - [Collision detection problem](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16923/382) - earlier and wanted to edit it, but the edit link was missing:

[image: missing links]

I thought that perhaps it was because the question was too new. However, on coming back I see that the links are still missing and that another < 2K reputation user has edited the post.

Other recent question - [How to create a "flying" game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/16927/382) - for example, do have the links.

Why are the "edit" and "retag" links missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has pending edits but you don't have enough rep to see them. I'll approve.

Comment: Thanks - it's odd not seeing these things. Having significantly higher rep on other sites is clearly spoiling me.